# plotly imagesc repeat yaxis labels

Tags: plotly-python

I have a wide matrix that I render using plotly express. Let's say:

```
import plotly.express as px
data=[[1, 25, 30, 50, 1], [20, 1, 60, 80, 30], [30, 60, 1, 5, 20]]
fig = px.imshow(data,
                labels=dict(x="Day of Week", y="Time of Day", color="Productivity"),
                x=['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
                y=['Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening']
               )
fig.update_xaxes(side="top")

fig.layout.height = 500
fig.layout.width = 500

fig.show()
```

For enhancing readability, I would like to repeat (or add an identical) yaxis on the right side of the matrix.

I tried to follow [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-plot-on-secondary-y-axis-with-plotly-express-in-python/)

```
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(domain=[0.3, 0.7]),
    # create 1st y axis
    yaxis=dict(
    title="yaxis1 title",),
    # create 2nd y axis
    yaxis2=dict(title="yaxis2 title", anchor="x", overlaying="y",
                side="right")
    )
```

but I cannot make it work with `imshow` as it does not accept a yaxis argument.

Any workarounds?

Comment: But you have only the data for y-axis, where are the data of second y-axis?  Please try to go through the link you added thoroughly. You will find you should have data for each additional y-axis.

Comment: cannot quite make the example work with an imshow...

Comment: What type of graph will you plot over heatmap? How will you combine between heatmap and other plot to have 2 y axes ?

Comment: I just want to have the same ticks both on the left and on the right

Comment: But you have the scale bar on the right, you will hide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer through the [plotly forum](https://community.plotly.com/t/imshow-with-double-yaxis/68896/2):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Create figure with secondary y-axis
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

data=[[1, 25, 30, 50, 1], [20, 1, 60, 80, 30], [30, 60, 1, 5, 20]]

fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(
                z=data,
                x=['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
                y=['Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening']
),secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(
                z=data,
                x=['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
                y=['Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening']
),secondary_y=True)

fig.update_xaxes(side="top")
fig.update_layout(xaxis_title="Day of Week", yaxis_title="Time of Day")

fig.show()
```

Note that adding the trace twice may be suboptimal, but it works.